# Understanding effective mass of electron for different $\rm Si$ orientation (001, 111, 110)

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I am somewhat familiar with the the constant energy surface of the conduction band picture for  $\rm Si$ in the $k$-space (6 ellipsoids). I am also aware that the size of the ellipsoids measured along the axes (longitudinal and transversal) gives you the effective mass of electrons associated with certain flow direction ($m^{*}_{x},m^{*}_{y},$ and $m^{*}_{z}$).

For example, 3D bulk silicon without any strain would be well characterized with the effective mass of electron of $m^{*}_{c} = \frac{g_v = 6}{2 /m^{*}_{l} + 2 / m^{*}_{t}  + 2 / m^{*}_{t}  }  $ where $m^{*}_{l}$ and $m^{*}_{t}$ are the effective mass associated with the size of the ellipsoid measured in the longitudinal and transversal directions and $g_v$ is the number of valley degeneracies.

In the case of strained  $\rm Si$ (usually the strain comes from heterostructure design, leading to some kind of lattice mismatch), it is often said that, for the $(100)$ surface case, where the quantum confinement direction is along the $(100)$ crystal direction, the $∆2$-band (in the $k_z$ axis) has the longitudinal mass ($m^{*}_{l}$) perpendicular to the semiconductor interface and therefore, only the lateral effective mass contributes in the xy in-plane direction, resulting in $m^{*}_{c} = 0.19m_0$. Also, because the larger mass ($m^{*}_{z}$, effective electron mass in the confinement direction) leads to smaller kinetic energy term, $∆2$-bands end up being the lower valley states than $∆4$-bands.

But, for Si $(110)$ and $(111)$ cases, I am confused by the effective mass table and 2D projection of the constant energy contour onto the momentum plane corresponding to the crystal direction.

Below are the table often shown and a 2D schematic representation of the constant-energy ellipses in Brilliouin zones for  $\rm Si$ $(100)$, $(110)$, and $(111)$ (the images are from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129156413500018) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263865993_Monte-Carlo_simulation_of_ultra-thin_film_silicon-on-insulator_MOSFETs)))

[image]

[image]

I am trying to match the entries of the $m_x$ and $m_y$ columns in the table to the dimensions of the ellipses in the 2D projection diagrams.

The (100) case seems to make sense. The middle ellipse (circle) have the shorter width in both x and y, meaning $0.19m_0$. The blue ellipses are wider in one direction, meaning $0.19m_0$ and $0.916m_0$  (I believe the indices of the mass (x and y) are not the same x and y as indices in $k_x$ and $k_y$  I think x and y in $m_x$ and $m_y$ are just supposed to represent the perpendicularity of the dimensions measured for each ellipse?

Regarding $(111)$, I have little clue how projecting the ellipsoides onto the plane perpendicular to $(111)$ crystal direction results in those $m_x$ and $m_y$. Also, I am confused by the labelling of the Brillouin zones. $k_x$ and $k_y$ in $(100)$ seem to correspond to $k_1 [100]$ and $k_2 [010]$. In the $(110)$ Brillouin zone picture, is $k_z$ along the vertical line of the Brillouin zone and is $k_x - k_y$ along the top horizontal line of the Brillouin zone? (in terms of the qualitative picture and the idea that all valleys have the same degeneracies because of the all valleys having the same effective mass in the confinement direction, there is no confusion.)